# A question about grammar

Tags: grammar, questions

I made up sentences:
"Jack feeds his chickens corn."
"Jack brings his wife flowers."
I wonder if the following questions are grammatically correct:
1) "Who does Jack feed corn?"
2) "Who does Jack feed corn to?"
3) "What does Jack feed to his chickens?"
4) "What does Jack bring his wife?"
5) "Who does Jack bring flowers?"
As far as I know, the following questions are correct:
"What does Jack feed his chickens?"
"What does Jack bring to his wife?"
"Who does Jack bring flowers to?"

Comment: I *think* all you're actually asking about here is whether or not to include the preposition ***to***. In principle, it's even "optional" in *Jack feeds **to** his chickens corn*, but actually no-one would ever say that. On the other hand, the preposition is ***required*** in monotransitive *Jack feeds corn **to** his chickens* (where *He feeds **them corn*** is "bitransitive" because it specifies both direct ***and*** indirect object without including prepositions). Whatever - ***to*** is optional in all your "question" examples.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you all very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sentences 1 and 5 are technically correct, but are not in current usage (at least in my part of the world). The others look right.

If your sentences (which are quite correct) were written as "Jack feeds corn to his chickens" and "Jack brings flowers to his wife" it might make it a little easier to see the relations between your statements and questions.

Comment: I don't object to "prepositionless" examples #1 and #5.

Comment: I am aware of them, but I do not recall ever hearing them. I will improve my answer to reflect that they are correct but uncommon.